# Adjust itemize horizontal

Tags: itemize

I am trying to adjust the itemize. I would like to push back the bullet to the left side and here is my code.

```
item \ressubheading{Project Engineer}{ABB
\begin{itemize}
    \resitem{Simulations of future expansions}
   \resitem{Technical capability in evaluating transmission}
     \end{itemize}
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Can you provide a code block that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile in order to replicate your current behaviour?

Comment: To copy pase the whole document might be long, but I am starting as follows
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.80}

Comment: Of course. That's why we want something small... or short. We call that a [minimal, working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) (MWE). Someone landing on this page has no reference as to what `\ressubheading` is defined as, and therefore wouldn't know how to solve your problem. So, again, create a *small* document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that allows us to copy-and-paste-and-compile the code and see exactly the issue that you're facing.

Comment: Which package defines the macros `\ressubheading` and `\resitem`?

Answer (score 2):

Since no MWE was provided, I assumed ur `\resitem` was similar to `\item`...
Maybe you could try using the `enumitem` package which allows customization of a list environment. In general, the bullet could be shifted right by adjusting ur `leftmargin` of your itemize environment:

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
  \item one 
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}
```

The MWE was as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent Default margin:
\begin{itemize}
  \item one 
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}

\noindent Adjusted margin:
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
  \item one 
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]